# Interoperability of hydraulic disc brakes and levers between model lines/manufacturers

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

My bike came with  Shimano Deore XT M765 hydraulic disc brakes and Shimano Deore XT M756 hydraulic levers Dual Control units.

I wonder whether the calipers from one manufacturer can be connected to the levers of another?

For example, can I connect 2018 Shimano XTR Race M9100 series calipers and rotors to Shimano XTR ST-M966/ BR-M965-F Hydraulic Disc Brake & Dual Control shifters?

Alternatively, can I connect Hope Tech 3 V4 calipers and rotors to the Shimano XTR ST-M966/ BR-M965-F Hydraulic Disc Brake & Dual Control shifter?

I want to mount this set-up on Fox Talas RL shocks.

What will be the issues of mounting these systems?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to bycicles.stackexchange! You are asking 3 question in one, only two of them are more closely related. It is better to split out your question about the shocks -- and make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

You should have no issues with your proposed Shimano-Shimano setup. You may  confirm this using the Shimano technical documents [si.shimano.com](http://si.shimano.com).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Hope Tech 3 V4 calipers with Shimano levers because Hope brakes generally use DOT fluid, which is incompatible with Shimano's mineral oil fluid. Technically, you can connect them, but the seals might/will fail.

However, there is a Hope RX-4 SH post mount caliper which is specifically marketed as compatible with Shimano drop bar levers and uses mineral oil. It's similar to Tech 3 V4 and even uses the same pad, I see no reason why it wouldn't work just as well for MTB applications as for road/gravel/CX.